# MongoDB Combine Unwinded Documents

Tags: mongodb

I am creating a mongo aggregate pipeline where I unwind a document by a field (doors) that is a list. Then, I filter by a condition on a property in the individual door.

How would I combine the filtered results back together such that the result is in its original form?

Here is an example of a document in my collection:

```
{ "uuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "name": "Building1",
  "doors": [
    {
     "doorUuid": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
     "creationTime": null
    },
    {
     "doorUuid": "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222",
     "creationTime": 1560194908942
    },
    {
     "doorUuid": "33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333",
     "creationTime": 1560195008942
    }
  ]
}
```

For example, if I wanted to filter out all doors with null creationTime's, the output I want would have the same structure above but with only two doors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$group` with `$push`:

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZH-zEUHxG6K)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$doors"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "doors.creationTime": {
        $ne: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {
        $last: "$name"
      },
      uuid: {
        $last: "$uuid"
      },
      doors: {
        $push: "$doors"
      }
    }
  }
])
```